# Importing global constants in single file components

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I have these two global constants in `@/assets/styles/constants.css`

```
@value headerColor: #4f4f6f;
@value brightRed: #e74c3c;
```

In a Vue template one value works, the other doesn't

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@value headerColor, brightRed from '@/assets/styles/constants.css';

.header {
  color: var(--headerColor); # this works
}

.button {
  background-color: var(--brightRed); # this doesn't work
}
</style>
```

Interestingly, I import `headerColor` in another component in the same way and it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub",
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "jest-serializer-vue"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
    ],
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure you are using `postcss` and the `postcss-modules-values` plugin and then configure your Webpack like below:

> colors.css

```
@value blue: #0c77f8;
@value red: #ff0000;
@value green: #aaf200;
```

> demo.css

```
/* import your colors... */
@value colors: "./colors.css";
@value blue, red, green from colors;

.button {
  color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

> Example webpack.config for `postcss-modules-values`

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var values = require('postcss-modules-values');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/index'],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: '/public/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss-loader') }
    ]
  },
  postcss: [
    values
  ],
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css', { allChunks: true })
  ]

};
```